# Google Structure data and breadcrumbs stopped showing

Tags: seo, structured-data

We are running the largest car website in the GCC  - www.drivearabia.com

All our breadcrumbs and structured data were working fine and now have stopped showing up on google. Our website master tools do not show any errors and properly show the breadcrumbs and structured data when we test.

Could someone let us know why they have stopped showing up?

Sample Url : http://www.drivearabia.com/ultimatecarbuyerguide/uae/carpage.php/Mercedes-Benz-CLA-45-AMG/2015-2016-/1227

Thanks a lot

Comment: Stack Overflow is **for questions related to programming**.  For non-programing SEO questions, you may be able to get help at [Webmasters Stack Exchange](webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The page is bloated with inline CSS and JavaScript, the response time is low and there's an extremely high HTML to content ratio on the site.  Your site was likely deemed unworthy of receiving the enhanced listing based on Google's tweak of the algorithm.  Google changes their algorithm about 300 times a year, any one of them could cause this type of behavior.

Comment: ..and the JavaScript console in the Developer Tools says "_Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined_" so maybe the crawler failed to render the page as [Google's Crawler now Understands JavaScript](http://www.business2community.com/seo/googles-crawler-now-understands-javascript-mean-0898263)